# CSS Animations : -Webkits in webkits

Tags: css, browser, webkit, css-animations

I keep seeing `css animation` code like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim{
  0{
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg); /* Is this line needed if it is already declared below? */
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; /* Is this line needed if it is already declared below? */
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px); /* Is this line needed if it is already declared below? */
  }
}
@keyframes anim{
  0{
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg); /* Is this line needed if it is already declared above? */
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; /* Is this line needed if it is already declared above? */
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px); /* Is this line needed if it is already declared above? */
    transform: perspective(400px);
  }
}
```

**QUESTION**

Is there any reason to declare **non** `-webkit` selectors within a `@-webkit-keyframes` code block and `-webkit` selectors within an `@keyframes` block?

Is the following equivelant to the code above?

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim{
  0{
    -webkit-transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:perspective(400px);
  }
}
@keyframes anim{
  0{
    transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    animation-timing-function:ease-in;
  }
  100%{
    transform:perspective(400px);
  }
}
```

---

Do we need to duplicate code within `@-webkit-keyframes` that is already stated in `@keyframes` where the `@-webkit` Is required.

If `@-webkit-keyframes` is not supported then why bother to declare `-webkit` functionality within the @keyframes block? Won't this be ignored also? And vice versa, If `@-webkit-keyframes` IS supported then the browser will use that block so why declare `-webkit` functionality in the `@keyframes` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we need to duplicate code within @-webkit-keyframes that is already stated in @keyframes where the @-webkit Is required.

The answer is "Yes".

The browser will use whatever syntax it recognizes and *ignore what it does not*...but it will always support the last version that it *does* support.

So if the broswer doesn't support `@keyframes` when unprefixed it will ignore the **whole statement** and fallback to the prefixed version.

Comment: But if `@-webkit-keyframes` is not supported then why bother to declare `-webkit` functionality within the `@keyframes` block? Won't this be ignored also? And vice versa, If `@-webkit-keyframes` IS supported then the browser will use that block so why declare `-webkit` functionality in the `@keyframes` block?

Comment: `-webkit` functionality is not a universal thing. `-webkit-transform` might be supported before `-webkit-keyframes` for instance or vice versa. So you have to mix&match for full support. Most prefixing systems like [**PrefixFree**](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) and [**AutoPrefixer**](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) will manage this for you.